# custom dialog box in java

Tags: java, swing, dialog, joptionpane

I was trying to build a custom dialog box using the following code.

```
public class CustomDialog
{

    JTextField firstName;
    JButton jb;
    public CustomDialog() 
    {
        firstName=new JTextField();
        jb= new JButton("Browse");
        final JComponent[] inputs = new JComponent[] 
        {
               new JLabel("SDK Path"),firstName,jb
        };
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputs, 
                "Enter the SDK Path", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);   
    }
```

The result of this code has the textfield followed by button and then OK in vertical manner. I wanted to have the button beside the OK Button. How can I do that??

How can I change OK Command's caption to "Save" ?

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, both issues in your question are descibed in the tutorial about [JDialog / JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button)